UTF-8 encodes single Unicode value to two different Hex values?
I am trying to encode Unicode character 192 in UTF-8 in Python as follows:
print(chr(192).encode())

Expected output:
b'\xc0'

Actual output:
b'\xc3\x80'

Where am i going wrong?

Your expectation is wrong. 192 is U+00C0 (hex) and is encoded as 0xC3 0x80 -- see the second row in the table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding .

You're not going wrong at all.  Many characters require more than a single byte when encoded in UTF-8.

P.S. only the Unicode code points from 0 to 127 map to the same byte value.  Anything higher than that will use multiple bytes, up to 4.

Thankyou both, i've got it. I now need to look at my decoding Javascript code, which is treating the two bytes separately

print(chr(192).encode('cp1252')) returns b'\xc0' (or use cp1254 or cp1258). (It's À (U+00C0,  Latin Capital Letter A With Grave)).
